# trying to add products from Product Activity(Product activity includes all the products in a certain sub-category)

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio

I am trying to add products from Product Activity(Product activity includes all the products in a certain sub-category) to  my cart, but whenever I am clicking on "ADD" or "+", "-" button, my Product Activity recycler view is not refreshing or updating, but the data in FireStore is updating. Here is my code.

**ProductAdapter.java**

```
public class ProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private List<ProductModel> productModelList;

public ProductAdapter(List<ProductModel> productModelList) {
    this.productModelList = productModelList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ProductAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.product_item_layout, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProductAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String productId = productModelList.get(position).getProductID();
    String productImage = productModelList.get(position).getProductImage();
    String productName = productModelList.get(position).getProductName();
    String productRatingNumber = productModelList.get(position).getProductRatingNumber();
    String productTotalNumberOfRatings = productModelList.get(position).getProductTotalNumberOfRatings();
    String productSP = productModelList.get(position).getProductSP();
    String productMRP = productModelList.get(position).getProductMRP();

    holder.setLayoutResources(productId, productImage, productName, productRatingNumber, productTotalNumberOfRatings, productSP
            , productMRP);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return productModelList.size();
}

@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public static long totalQty = 0;
    public static float total_price = 0;
    public static String productAdapterId;
    public static String productAdapterSP;

    private ImageView productImage;
    private TextView productName;
    private TextView productRatingNumber;
    private TextView productTotalNumberOfRatings;
    private TextView productSP;
    private TextView productMRP;

    public static TextView totalPrice;

    public static ImageButton add;
    public static ImageButton sub;
    public static TextView qty;
    public static LinearLayout addButton;
    public static LinearLayout addSubQty;

    private Dialog signInDialog;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        signInDialog = new Dialog(itemView.getContext());
        signInDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_sign_in_sign_up);
        signInDialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        signInDialog.setCancelable(true);
        Button signInButton = signInDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_button_sign_in);
        Button signUpButton = signInDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_button_sign_up);
        final Intent registerIntent = new Intent(itemView.getContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
        signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                disableCloseButton = true;
                signInDialog.dismiss();
                signUp = false;
                itemView.getContext().startActivity(registerIntent);
            }
        });
        signUpButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                disableCloseButton = true;
                signInDialog.dismiss();
                signUp = true;
                itemView.getContext().startActivity(registerIntent);
            }
        });

        productImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_item_image);
        productName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_item_name);
        productRatingNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_item_rating_number);
        productTotalNumberOfRatings = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_item_total_rating);
        productSP = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_item_sp);
        productMRP = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_item_mrp);
        totalPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_item_total_price);
        add = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_item_linear_layout_add);
        sub = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_item_linear_layout_minus);
        qty = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_item_linear_layout_number);

        addButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_item_add_layout);
        addSubQty = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_item_add_sub_layout);
    }

    public void setLayoutResources(final String productID, final String productImage, final String productName,
                                   String productRatingNumber, String productTotalNumberOfRatings,
                                   final String productSP, final String productMRP) {
        productAdapterId = productID;
        productAdapterSP = productSP;
        if(DBQueries.cartListIds.size() == 0){
            DBQueries.loadCartIds(itemView.getContext(), false);
        }
        if (DBQueries.cartListIds.contains(ProductAdapter.ViewHolder.productAdapterId)) {
            int index = DBQueries.cartListIds.indexOf(ProductAdapter.ViewHolder.productAdapterId);
            totalQty = DBQueries.cartListQuantities.get(index);
            total_price = Float.parseFloat(productAdapterSP) * totalQty;
            addButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            addSubQty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            qty.setText(String.valueOf(ProductAdapter.ViewHolder.totalQty));
            totalPrice.setText("Rs. " + String.valueOf(total_price) + "/-");
        } else {
            ProductAdapter.ViewHolder.addButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ProductAdapter.ViewHolder.addSubQty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            totalPrice.setText("Rs. " + String.valueOf(total_price) + "/-");
        }

        Glide.with(itemView.getContext()).load(productImage).apply(new RequestOptions().placeholder(R.drawable.product_placeholder)).into(this.productImage);
        this.productName.setText(productName);
        this.productRatingNumber.setText(productRatingNumber);
        this.productTotalNumberOfRatings.setText(productTotalNumberOfRatings + " ratings");
        this.productSP.setText("Rs. " + productSP + "/-");
        this.productMRP.setText("Rs. " + productMRP + "/-");

        addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (currentUser != null) {
                    if (!RUNNING_CART_QUERY) {
                        RUNNING_CART_QUERY = true;
                        Map<String, Object> cartMap = new HashMap<>();
                        cartMap.put("product_id_" + cartListIds.size(), productID);
                        cartMap.put("qty_" + cartListIds.size(), (long) 1);
                        cartMap.put("list_size", cartListIds.size() + 1);
                        DBQueries.firebaseFirestore.collection("USERS").document(currentUser.getUid())
                                .collection("USER_DATA")
                                .document("MY_CART").update(cartMap)
                                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                            totalQty = 1;
                                            cartListIds.add(productID);
                                            cartListQuantities.add(totalQty);
                                            addButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                            addSubQty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                            total_price = Float.parseFloat(productAdapterSP) * totalQty;
                                            qty.setText(String.valueOf(totalQty));
                                            totalPrice.setText("Rs. " + String.valueOf(total_price) + "/-");
                                            cartItemModelList.add(new CartItemModel(
                                                    productID,
                                                    productImage,
                                                    productName,
                                                    productSP,
                                                    productMRP,
                                                    totalQty));
                                            Toast.makeText(itemView.getContext(), "Product added to cart!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        } else {
                                            totalQty = 0;
                                            String error = task.getException().getMessage();
                                            Toast.makeText(itemView.getContext(), error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                        RUNNING_CART_QUERY = false;
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                } else {
                    signInDialog.show();
                }
            }
        });
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!RUNNING_CART_QUERY) {
                    RUNNING_CART_QUERY = true;
                    totalQty++;
                    total_price = Float.parseFloat(productSP) * totalQty;
                    final int index = cartListIds.indexOf(productID);
                    Map<String, Object> cartMap = new HashMap<>();
                    cartMap.put("product_id_" + index, productID);
                    cartMap.put("qty_" + index, totalQty);
                    DBQueries.firebaseFirestore.collection("USERS").document(currentUser.getUid())
                            .collection("USER_DATA")
                            .document("MY_CART").update(cartMap)
                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                        cartListQuantities.set(cartListIds.indexOf(productID), totalQty);
                                        cartItemModelList.get(index).setProductQuantity(totalQty);
                                        qty.setText(String.valueOf(totalQty));
                                        totalPrice.setText("Rs. " + String.valueOf(total_price) + "/-");
                                    } else {
                                        totalQty--;
                                        total_price = Float.parseFloat(productSP) * totalQty;
                                        String error = task.getException().getMessage();
                                        Toast.makeText(itemView.getContext(), error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                    RUNNING_CART_QUERY = false;
                                }
                            });
                }
            }
        });
        sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!RUNNING_CART_QUERY) {
                    RUNNING_CART_QUERY = true;
                    totalQty--;
                    total_price = Float.parseFloat(productSP) * totalQty;
                    final int index = cartListIds.indexOf(productID);
                    if (totalQty == 0) {
                        DBQueries.removeFromCartList(itemView.getContext(), index);
                    } else {
                        Map<String, Object> cartMap = new HashMap<>();
                        cartMap.put("product_id_" + index, productID);
                        cartMap.put("qty_" + index, totalQty);
                        DBQueries.firebaseFirestore.collection("USERS").document(currentUser.getUid())
                                .collection("USER_DATA")
                                .document("MY_CART").update(cartMap)
                                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                            cartListQuantities.set(cartListIds.indexOf(productID), totalQty);
                                            cartItemModelList.get(index).setProductQuantity(totalQty);
                                            qty.setText(String.valueOf(ProductAdapter.ViewHolder.totalQty));
                                            totalPrice.setText("Rs. " + String.valueOf(total_price) + "/-");
                                        } else {
                                            totalQty++;
                                            total_price = Float.parseFloat(productSP) * totalQty;
                                            String error = task.getException().getMessage();
                                            Toast.makeText(itemView.getContext(), error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                        RUNNING_CART_QUERY = false;
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent productDetailsIntent = new Intent(itemView.getContext(), ProductDetailsActivity.class);
                productDetailsIntent.putExtra("PRODUCT_ID", productID);
                itemView.getContext().startActivity(productDetailsIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

**loading cart in DBQueries.java**

```
public static void loadCartIds(final Context context, final boolean loadProducts) {
    if (!RUNNING_CART_QUERY) {
        RUNNING_CART_QUERY = true;
        cartListIds.clear();
        cartListQuantities.clear();
        cartItemModelList.clear();
        firebaseFirestore.collection("USERS").document(currentUser.getUid())
                .collection("USER_DATA").document("MY_CART").get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < (long) task.getResult().get("list_size"); i++) {
                                final String id = task.getResult().get("product_id_" + i).toString();
                                final long qty = (long) task.getResult().get("qty_" + i);
                                cartListIds.add(id);
                                cartListQuantities.add(qty);
                                if (addToCartButton != null) {
                                    if (cartListIds.contains(productId)) {
                                        int index = cartListIds.indexOf(productId);
                                        quantity = cartListQuantities.get(index);
                                        addToCartButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        addSubLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        totalPriceContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        addSubLayoutText.setText(String.valueOf(quantity));
                                        totalPrice.setText("Rs. " + String.valueOf(Float.parseFloat(SELLING_PRICE) * quantity) + "/-");
                                    } else {
                                        addToCartButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        addSubLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        totalPriceContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    }
                                }
                                if (ProductAdapter.ViewHolder.addButton != null) {
                                    if (cartListIds.contains(ProductAdapter.ViewHolder.productAdapterId)) {
                                        int index = cartListIds.indexOf(ProductAdapter.ViewHolder.productAdapterId);
                                        ProductAdapter.ViewHolder.totalQty = cartListQuantities.get(index);
                                        ProductAdapter.ViewHolder.total_price = Float.parseFloat(
                                                ProductAdapter.ViewHolder.productAdapterSP) * ProductAdapter.ViewHolder.totalQty;
                                        ProductAdapter.ViewHolder.addButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        ProductAdapter.ViewHolder.addSubQty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        ProductAdapter.ViewHolder.qty.setText(String.valueOf(ProductAdapter.ViewHolder.totalQty));
                                        ProductAdapter.ViewHolder.totalPrice.setText("Rs. " + String.valueOf(
                                                ProductAdapter.ViewHolder.total_price) + "/-");
                                    } else {
                                        ProductAdapter.ViewHolder.addButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        ProductAdapter.ViewHolder.addSubQty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    }
                                }
                                if(loadProducts){
                                    firebaseFirestore.collection("PRODUCTS")
                                            .document(id)
                                            .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                                            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                                cartItemModelList.add(new CartItemModel(
                                                        id,
                                                        task.getResult().get("image_1").toString(),
                                                        task.getResult().get("name").toString(),
                                                        task.getResult().get("sp").toString(),
                                                        task.getResult().get("mrp").toString(),
                                                        qty));
                                                CartFragment.cartItemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                            }else {
                                                String error = task.getException().getMessage();
                                                Toast.makeText(context, error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            String error = task.getException().getMessage();
                            Toast.makeText(context, error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        RUNNING_CART_QUERY = false;
                    }
                });
    }
}

public static void removeFromCartList(final Context context, final int index) {
    cartListIds.remove(index);
    cartListQuantities.remove(index);
    Map<String, Object> cartMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < cartListIds.size(); i++) {
        cartMap.put("product_id_" + i, cartListIds.get(i));
        cartMap.put("qty_" + i, cartListQuantities.get(i));
    }
    cartMap.put("list_size", (long) cartListIds.size());
    firebaseFirestore.collection("USERS").document(currentUser.getUid())
            .collection("USER_DATA").document("MY_CART")
            .set(cartMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                if (addToCartButton != null) {
                    quantity = 0;
                    addToCartButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    addSubLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    totalPriceContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                if (ProductAdapter.ViewHolder.addButton != null){
                    ProductAdapter.ViewHolder.totalPrice.setText("Rs. " + String.valueOf(0.0) + "/");
                    ProductAdapter.ViewHolder.addButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    ProductAdapter.ViewHolder.addSubQty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                if(cartItemModelList.size()!=0){
                    cartItemModelList.remove(index);
                    CartFragment.cartItemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                Toast.makeText(context, "Removed Successfully from cart!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                String error = task.getException().getMessage();
                Toast.makeText(context, error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            RUNNING_CART_QUERY = false;
        }
    });
}
```

[my product layout image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OtRZ.jpg)

Comment: How are you sure that the onComplete in loadCartIds, is completed before the next if /else statement in setLayoutResources get's executed.
Make sure this if (DBQueries.cartListIds.contains(ProductAdapter.ViewHolder.productAdapterId)) {} statement works after the data is added into the DB

Comment: the data in product list is being added fine with all the quantities pre-set, the only problem I am facing whenever I am interacting with onClick methods on ADD, +, - buttons in product activity. I am facing various problems like, the text is not change in textview on adding or subtracting, the product gets deleted from cart but in product activity nothing happens.

Comment: Ok, I see what is happening, you need to move all the logic of setLayoutResources out of the viewHolder and into activity. To do that, use interface to call up the function in activity which does all the logic, then after adding to db, in onComplete, you need to call the adapter.notifyItemChanged()

Comment: Ok, you mean that after my firebase query is update i need to call a onCallBack method from adapter in product activity and update my adapter from there, ok I will try that and let you know whether it is working or not.